# Order of CSS rules applied to child elements

Tags: html, css

I wonder how the CSS rules applied to the child elements.

The `h2`'s `gray` style is been overriding because there is a parent level style `.level2 h2`with `blue` color.

But the `.level1 h2` is not applying the same way.

Please see the below example.

```css
.level1 h2 {
  color: green;
}
.level2 h2 {
  color: blue;
}
h2 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it would still work @Leothelion, since this is a descendant selector, not to be confused with the direct descendent selection `>`

Comment: @GMchris ok thank you for information :)

Answer (score 3):

It's all about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and inheritance.

> The notion of a “cascade” is at the heart of CSS (just look at its
>   name). It ultimately determines which properties will modify a given
>   element. The cascade is tied to three main concepts: importance,
>   specificity and source order. The cascade follows these three steps to
>   determine which properties to assign to an element. By the end of this
>   process, the cascade has assigned a weight to each rule, and this
>   weight determines which rule takes precedence, when more than one
>   applies.

It also depend of the **order** in the stylesheet if both selectors have the same specificity.

```css
    .level2 h2 {
        color: blue;
    }
    .level1 h2 {
        color: green;
    }

    h2 {
        color: gray;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">
           <h2>test</h2>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**Source :** https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of [CSS  Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> ## The concept
>
> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed
>   of CSS selectors of different sorts.
>
> ## How is it calculated?
>
> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration,
>   determined by the number of each selector type in the matching
>   selector. When specificity is equal to any of the multiple
>   declarations, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the
>   element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by
>   multiple declarations. As per CSS rules directly targeted element will
>   always take precedence over rules that an element inherits from an
>   ancestor.

Where :

- `.level1 h2` and `.level2 h2` will have a specificity of : `0 0 1 1`

While:

- `h2` only has a specificity of: `0 0 0 1`

therefore `h2` is **less** specific.

It will prevail the latest style applied if having the **same** specificity

You can test/calculate specificity [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

---

#### Snippet with level2 as last style applied

```css
.level1 h2 {
  color: green;
}
.level2 h2 {
  color: blue;
}
h2 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Snippet with level1 as last style applied

```css
.level2 h2 {
  color: blue;
}
.level1 h2 {
  color: green;
}
h2 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.level2 h2` is given more importance as it's declared further down in the stylesheet. And it's also more important than h2, because it's composed of a tag name AND a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Since the specifity here is the same for ".level1 h2" and ".level2 h2", the browser looks at the order it is declared in the CSS.

The "h2" tag that makes the tag gray has lower specifity, so that will alwayss be overridden by the other declarations.

```css
h2 {
  color: gray;
}

/* Situation 1, level 2 declared first */
.situation1.level2 h2 {
  color: blue;
}

.situation1.level1 h2 {
  color: green;
}

/* Situation 1, level 2 declared last */
.situation2.level1 h2 {
  color: green;
}
.situation2.level2 h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Level 2 declared <b>first</b> 
  <div class="level1 situation1">
      <div class="level2 situation1">
         <h2>test</h2>
      </div>
   </div>


  Level 2 declared <b>last</b> 
  <div class="level1 situation2">
      <div class="level2 situation2">
         <h2>test</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
```